# Тире или дефис?

Tags: орфография

"Не менее трех врачей(-)специалистов организации здравоохранения".

Comment: Lapf, не хотите - не отвечайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого слова врач-специалист нет. В Вашем предложении, скорее всего, приложение, стоящее в конце предложения. (Хорошо бы его полностью видеть!) Ставится тире. А если приложение не в конце, а в середине предложения, то с двух сторон запятые.

Comment: Liana, если не секрет, чем Вы занимаетесь? У меня впечатление, что мы вместе с Вами все время что-то редактируем...Какие-то инструкции, официальные документы?

Comment: Комиссия, как правило, состоит из председателя и членов комиссии: не менее трех врачей — специалистов организации здравоохранения, врача-нарколога,...

Comment: Так и есть, я стилистический редактор. Да, имею дело с инструкциями, нормативными документами и т.д.

Comment: Это здесь имеет какое-то значение? :)

Comment: Из правил форума: Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с написанием или проверкой текста: форум не является фриланс-биржей. В частности, не допускаются вопросы...
    
    смысл которых которых сводится к проверке грамотности элементарного текста, например, "Правильно ли написана фраза, исправьте ошибки, пожалуйста?"

Comment: Lapf, я не прошу исправить за меня ошибки. Я лишь прошу помочь мне в спорных моментах, возникающих в ходе моей работы. И разве это элементарный случай? Не хочу вести полемику. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Это элементарный случай - правило из программы 8 класса средней школы. Мне кажется, Вас русский язык не интересует. Потому и вопросы однозначны (правильно или нет, и никогда почему), и даже повторяются. В полемику вступать не буду, но и работать заочным  помощником стилистического редактора - тоже.